Exception has occurred. _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value) error on widget model
This is my code to show thumbnail or food image in my homescreen. But i dont know why the image doesnt appear in my emulator and its showing _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value) at the commented line.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Model/menus.dart';

class InfoDesignWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //this class will receive
  Menus? model;
  BuildContext? context;

  InfoDesignWidget({this.model, this.context});

  @override
  State<InfoDesignWidget> createState() => _InfoDesignWidgetState();
}

class _InfoDesignWidgetState extends State<InfoDesignWidget> {
  String? thumbnailUrl;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.amber,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 235,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Divider(
                height: 2,
                thickness: 3,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
              //Merchant image
              Image.network(
                widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!, //here is the error message
                height: 200.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .97,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 2.0),
              //Merchant name
              Text(
                widget.model!.menuName!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 2,
                thickness: 3,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
              Text(
                widget.model!.menuInfo!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have tried many solution but still its there. I cant even remove the null check cuz its compulsory.

Null assert is risky when we don't check the in prior. You can do
if(widget.model?.thumbnailUrl!=null)
 Image.network(..),

Also you can use empty string as default
Image.network(
  widget.model?.thumbnailUrl ?? "", // Provide a default empty string if null
  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
    return Text("Your Image on Error");
  },
)

You can do the same for others; Not about this issue  but use MediaQuery.sizeOf or layoutBuilder to get the size.

          Image.network(
            widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!, //here is the error message
            height: 200.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .97,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),

// Replace to this code
Image.network(
widget.model?.thumbnailUrl ?? "",
height: 200.0,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .97,
fit: BoxFit.cover,
errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
Icon(Icons.error),     // you can change any widget to handle error
),


i did it but why my app pause in homescreen when running?

Can you please provide more details and also let me know what network URL you are receiving for the image?
